# How to move data between HTML and Flask in real time?

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend

I am building a basic python application that pulls news data, for now just article names and pictures, and displays them in a card swipe, Tinder like format. My app just consists of a python script to get the news data, a flask app, and an HTML file. However, I am not sure how to pull the article images in real time from my python app file and display them on the HTML page.
Here is the js function in the HTML file that deals with the card content (the image):

```
push() {

                let card = document.createElement('div')

                card.classList.add('card')

                card.style.backgroundImage =
                    //pull from python app

                this.board.insertBefore(card, this.board.firstChild)

       }
```

The news API I am using returns data in a json format that looks like this (note the urlToImage portion):

```
{u'description': u'CNN political analyst Carl Bernstein discusses with Don Lemon about how members of the Republican party are enabling President Donald Trump\'s "authoritarian" behavior.', u'title': u"Bernstein says Republicans are enabling Trump as 'mad king'", u'url': u'https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2020/11/20/carl-bernstein-trump-republican-party-mad-king-sot-vpx.cnn', u'author': None, u'publishedAt': u'2020-11-20T07:44:46Z', u'content': None, u'source': {u'id': u'cnn', u'name': u'CNN'}, u'urlToImage': u'https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/201120000727-bernstein-ctn-mad-king-sot-vpx-super-tease.jpg'}
```

And here is my simple flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from news import searchQuery
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax on the frontend (HTML) and make a new endpoint (route) no the backend (flask).

on the HTML

```
function push(news_id){
     $.ajax({
        // news_id will be used as the id of the image.
        url : '/getImage/' + news_id,
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(response){
          // change the div background here
        }
        error : function(){
          // Error
        }
     });
}
```

On the flask

```
@app.route('getImage/<news_id>', methods = ['GET'])
def getImage(news_id):
   # any logic to retrieve the image path/url from database
   # example
   news = News.query.get(news_id)
   return jsonify(news.news_image_url)
```

Your app (code you gave) is kind of simple though, this is just the basic concept.
There is a lot of things to be explored more.

Comment: appreciate the response, I will try it out. Im definitely looking to extend it, possibly add a machine learning recommender and other additions.